# 'Play run' exits when triggered through hudson but works fine from commandline

Tags: playframework, hudson

Running into a weird issue with hudson and play. When running/starting a new play project/app through the commandline (using 'play run' command) the app starts fine and waits until you hit CTL+D (which is expected). So imagine a shell script 'run-play.sh' with the following content,

```
cd my-play-app
play run
echo "Play exited"
```

When the above script is run on my box locally I see the following output,

```
--- (Running the application from SBT, auto-reloading is enabled) ---

[info] play - Listening for HTTP on /0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0%0:9000

(Server started, use Ctrl+D to stop and go back to the console...)
```

But when the same command is run through hudson UI (which ssh's to the same local box) the script immediately exits and says "play exited". I have no clue why running the same command through hudson would behave differently than running it directly on the box. We're on Play 2.2.1

Answer (score 0):

Try backgrounding `play run` via `play run &` or suspending and resuming it. You'll get some message about `tty`. I think when you run the script, you need to make sure that the shell supports tty. Specifically, `ssh` has a parameter `-t` that enables tty "Force pseudo-tty allocation". Try running your script by passing it through ssh with and without `-t`, also by using an addition `-t -t` (see the ssh man-page).